# the UIImageView is not visible in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I add a UIImageView In the UITableView Cell,but it is not visible. 
But when you selected the row, the image is visible, it is so puzzled.
can you help me ?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *) reuseIdentifier    
{  
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"]];       
        cellImage.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 20, 20);
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
        self.textLabel.text = @"parent";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add `cellImage` as an **`accessoryView`**.

```
[cell setAccessoryView: cellImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should first init your imageView and set its Frame 
Then you should set its image.See the given code for the CustomtableViewCell

```
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 80, 80)];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Now in your controller's tableViewCellforrowatindexpath method 
ues the given code

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"123.jpg"];
```

This will add image at ur imgView